# Cant change other container images with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file, input, this

Hy guys 
I am trying to make more user friendly attach image input files and a script I have only changes first image when person selects something. Any idea how to fix it ? 
Thx in advance !

```
  $(function() {
     $("input:file").on(this).change(function (){
      $(this).parent().find('.empty_input_file').hide();
      $(this).parent().find('.full_input_file').show();
     });
  });
```

[Check out example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ESM4m/178/)

Answer (score 0):

Your input have the same ID and IDs **must be unique*

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ESM4m/179/)**

```
<div class="image-upload" title="Select image">
    <label for="file-input1">
        <img class="empty_input_file" src="http://goo.gl/pB9rpQ" />
        <img class="full_input_file" src="http://zqapps.com/DraperDarkFlow/images/Icon-Blue.png" />
    </label>
    <input id="file-input1" type="file" name="d4p_attachment[]">
    <br/>
</div>
<div class="image-upload" title="Select image">
    <label for="file-input2">
        <img class="empty_input_file" src="http://goo.gl/pB9rpQ" />
        <img class="full_input_file" src="http://zqapps.com/DraperDarkFlow/images/Icon-Blue.png" />
    </label>
    <input id="file-input2" type="file" name="d4p_attachment[]">
    <br/>
</div>
```